# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.struts2.StrutsJUnit4TestCase.executeAction(StrutsJUnit4TestCase.java:134)

Tags: java, struts2, nullpointerexception, junit4, spring-3

I'm using Struts2, Spring3 for my application, when I doing jUnit4 test for my application I'm getting this error:

```
null java.lang.NullPointerException  
at org.apache.struts2.StrutsJUnit4TestCase.executeAction(StrutsJUnit4TestCase.java:134)     
at com.junitaction.HelloWorldTest.testGetString2(HelloWorldTest.java:76)    
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)   
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)     
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)   
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)   
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)    
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)     
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)   
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
```

the error occurs when I call the `executeAction` method. How to resolve this problem.

**my jar files:**

> antlr-2.7.2.jar, asm-3.3.jar, commons-fileupload-1.3.jar,
> commons-io-2.0.1.jar, commons-lang-2.4.jar, commons-lang3-3.1.jar,
> commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, freemarker-2.3.19.jar,
> javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar, ognl-3.0.6.jar,
> org.springframework.web.servlet-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar,
> spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar, spring-aspects-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar,
> spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar, spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar,
> spring-context-support-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar, spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar,
> spring-expression-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar, spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar,
> spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar, struts2-core-2.3.15.1.jar,
> struts2-junit-plugin-2.3.15.1.jar, struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.15.1.jar,
> xwork-core-2.3.15.1.jar.

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

 <struts>        
     <constant name="struts.objectFactory" 
     value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory"/>
         <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
         <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
             <action name="helloworld" class="helloWorldClass">
                 <result>/success.jsp</result>
             </action>
         </package> 
 </struts>
```

**`web.xml`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>            
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> 
</web-app>
```

**`appplicationContext.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="helloWorldClass" class="com.junitaction.HelloWorld" >
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [struts2 junit plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/junit) to the project and extend your tests from `StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase`.

And in `struts.xml` you should use

```
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
```

to make the spring able to manage your actions.

Comment: Post the full stacktrace, also include the version you use.

Comment: Also needed `javax.servlet jsp-api`

Comment: 2.0 or 2.1, this is included in the JavaEE6 package `javax.servlet.jsp.jar`, unfortunately without version info. So, use maven.

Comment: i've placed that jar but again im getting null pointer exception only.

Comment: You should place it in `web-inf/lib` and redeploy.

Comment: @Developer-j You have also changed the `objectFactory`, so modify the code in configuration file.

Comment: i changed my Object Factory to **<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />** but again the same Nullpointer Exception Occurs.

Comment: Is it all jars listed above?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, those jars only im using and apache-tomcat7.0.42 for server

Comment: then you have to rework those jars are incomplete or have a wrong version, try maven to download required jars.

Comment: we are not using maven, so i cant use maven for junit, is there any other way to do it means please help me

Comment: this is not a question, remember either you follow me or I give up I'm not kidding here.

Comment: I've already told you, create [this](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-using-maven-to-manage-artifacts-and-to-build-the-application.html) app and look into web-inf/lib to see what jars have been downloaded, compare with your project, convert your project to the maven project, create pom.xml, add dependency, use maven command to resolve dependencies. Then tell me what happened.